# Rad Datagrid binds in page load but not in another function?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

This one's really stumping me. And it looks simple. I have a telerik: RadGrid on an aspx page and I'm using a web service to get a table and bind it. I bind it once on page_load and when a node from a tree is clicked i want to bind it again displaying new info. However, when trying to bind from this function the grid comes up null. For right, now I'm using the same service call to bind.

Here's my server code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



            using (ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient myService = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient())
            {


                CurrentDemog = Convert.ToInt32(Session["demog"].ToString());

                DataTable lookupTbl = myService.getTable();
                LookupGrid.DataSource = lookupTbl;
                LookupGrid.DataBind();
            }


    }



   protected void LookupsTree_NodeClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {

        RadTreeNode currNode = e.Node;
        if (currNode.Nodes.Count == 0) {
            if (currNode.ParentNode.Text != "Treatments" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currNode.Text))
            {
                selectedNode = currNode.Text;

                 using (ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient myService = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient())
                 {
                     Util.ClearGrid(ref LookupGrid);
                     DataTable lookupTbl = myService.getTable();

                     LookupGrid.DataSource = lookupTbl;
                     LookupGrid.DataBind();
                 }


            }

        }

    }``
```

Here's my client code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="LookupGrid">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="LookupGrid"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

```
     <telerik:RadGrid ID="LookupGrid" runat="server" BackColor="Gray" 
         BorderColor="#404040" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" 
         Skin="MetroTouch">

     </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Page.IsPostback in your Page_Load method. Otherwise data will be loaded every time you do anything that causes page to be reloaded.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            using (ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient myService = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient())
            {
                CurrentDemog = Convert.ToInt32(Session["demog"].ToString());

                DataTable lookupTbl = myService.getTable();
                LookupGrid.DataSource = lookupTbl;
                LookupGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens here is that you load your grid view and click the button. When you do this Page_Load method is called before the event handler. This most probably causes if statements in the event handler to be false causing data not to be loaded.

Here is a good reading on this topic: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I added the isPostback check to my page_load but still the same problem. Would I have to add an ispostback to my node click event? Also, my grid is not bound in the page_load like you have done here. Will that cause a problem?